# Find & change string

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-processing, text-parsing

I'm trying to figure out, how to change a certain part of a string in Python. I'm very very beginner in text processing and in Python. It took me two hours to come up with the piece of code below and it doesn't work. Could you please tell me why?

I need to do the following: слово б word --> слово N[б] word

Here is what i have so far:

```
# f is the input file, unformatted, anouns is the output file. Right now i get anouns=f,
# i.e. no changes are made to the lines written into anouns.  

def toNoun(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(0) == ' б ': return ' N[б] '
    elif matchobj.group(0) == ' д ': return ' N[д] '
    elif matchobj.group(0) == ' в ': return ' N[в] '
    else: return 'N[й]'

lines = f.readlines() # list of lines

for line in lines:
   if re.match(ur"(?u)^.* ([бдв]|й){1} .*", line):
     anouns.write(re.sub(' [бдв]|й ',toNoun,line))
```

From the input file:

aбаде й Ewigkeit f

aбат д Alphabet n

aвстрихо в Österreicher m

aга д Wiege f

aгар д Gravieren n,Schnitzerei f

aгархо в Schnitzer m,Graveur m ,дечиг агархо Holzschnitzer m

Comment: your `toNoun` method body doesn't look properly indented - did you paste in the code properly or is that how you have written it?

Comment: changed it in the question. I have it right in my code.

Comment: can you paste a few lines of your file please as I want to check if your reg exp pattern is correct

Comment: i added it to the question above.

Comment: I found the reason why it doesn't work -- Unicode. Yet to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
letters = ['б', 'д', 'в'] # add more letters here
text = "слово б word, слово д word" # you can use your "line" as text
for letter in letters:
    letterToReplace = ' '+letter+' '
    newString = ' N['+letter+'] '
    text = text.replace(letterToReplace , newString )
print text
>> слово N[б] word, слово N[д] word
```

Comment: How to do it universally, so that it works for different alone standing letters, not only for б?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to adapt it for my problem, doing it right now. Could you tell me please, why would you choose this method over the one I tried, with re.sub?

Comment: with this method I do some extra iterations.. as in my file I have only of those letters, but still will do the work for all б, д, в etc. Can we do better? :)

Comment: `replace()` is what I used before, I don't know how `re.sub` works. Instead of `newString = ' N['+letter+'] '` you can use your `toNoun` , also add break in the end of for loop